# this.state.push is undefined on reactjs when trying to use a onclick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

I am trying to create a random color generator which will set new random background colors from an array to the element when I click.

I created the handleClick() function on the first span, but it's showing me this when I click it:

> TypeError: this.state.push is not a function

Heres my ColorShifter file:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Colorshifter.css";

class ColorShifter extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    colors: [
      "#3498db",
      " #8d989f",
      "#9c6faa",
      "#97aa6f",
      "#487459",
      "#48746f",
      "#cfbd67",
      "#df811d",
      "#f06653",
      "#f0e753",
      "#f70000",
      "#ec00f7",
      "#1d21b0",
      "#464664",
      "#a29967",
      "#bc8abd",
      "#8abdb0",
      "#397254",
      "#e6e6d0"
    ]
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = [];
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.colors.length);
    this.setState((this.state[e] = this.state[r]));
  }

  render() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.colors.length; i++) {
      let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.colors.length);
      const colorStyle = {
        backgroundColor: this.props.colors[ran]
      };
      this.state.push(colorStyle);
    }       
    return (
      <div className="div">
        <span onClick={this.handleClick(0)}>
          <p style={this.state[0]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[1]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[2]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[3]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[4]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[5]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[6]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[7]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[8]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[9]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[11]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[10]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[12]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[13]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[14]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[15]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[16]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
        <span>
          <p style={this.state[17]} className="container"></p>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ColorShifter;
```

My main App.js file:

```
import React from "react";
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import "./App.css";
import ColorShifter from "./ColorShifter";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ColorShifter />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my css file (optional):

```
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.div {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `() => this.handleClick(0)`. `this.handleClick(0)` alone is evaluated immediately, and the value is used as a callback, which isn't what you want - you need to provide a function, but you have provided undefined, as handleClick returns void.

Comment: I am still getting the same error when I use this method inside my onclick function

Comment: In react state is immutable, you can't use this.state.push, you have to use this.setState if you are trying to change your state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this block:

```
<span onClick={this.handleClick(0)}>
    <p style={this.state[0]} className="container"></p>
</span>
```

You should pass function to `onClick` event, not function invocation. To pass your own params use this syntax `onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)}`

At this block:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.props.colors.length; i++) {
    let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.colors.length);
    const colorStyle = {
        backgroundColor: this.props.colors[ran]
    };
    this.state.push(colorStyle);
}
```

To update the react state, use this syntax instead:

`this.setState({...this.state.colors, colorStyle})`

Your colors state initialization should look like this:

`this.state.colors = []`

You should change the handleClick definition like this, as well:

`handleClick = (e, value) => {...}`

Comment: this.state.setState({...this.state.colors, colorStyle}) is not a function. that's what I am getting

Comment: @Prottay: To change the color on clicking on span, why you need the for loop in render function ? I do not understand that point.

Answer (score 1):

In your handleclick you are not setting setState() correctly. You have this:

```
this.setState((this.state[e] = this.state[r]));
```

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
this.setState(currentState => {
  return {...currentState, [this.state[e]]: this.state[r] }
});
```

Comment: same error. Is the problem on my span where I called the function?